# Postgres now() date to typescript date

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, date, prisma

I have a date `2022-08-04 08:16:32.716904 // without timezone` which was created with now() function in SQL as a timestamp with (6) milliseconds precision (i.e `DateTime @db.Timestamp(6)` with [primsa](https://prisma.io)).

How can I create a `new Date()` object in typescript to match this exact precision ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert javascript date to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ssssssZ (6 digit microseconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73275944/convert-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-ssssssz-6-digit-microseconds)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `new Date("2022-08-04 08:16:32.716904")`, it should create a date as you want to.

Another (complicated) way to do it would be to isolate all time units of your timestamp and to use this constructor `new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

Comment: Your solution` new Date("2022-08-04 08:16:32.716904")` returns a null date object and ` new Date("2022-08-04T08:16:32.716904")` returns `2022-08-04T08:16:32.716Z`

Comment: Isn't the second result what you're looking for ?

Comment: Nope, not the same date at all